# Cannot convert timestamp to date

Tags: php, timestamp

I have this `timestamp`: `2018-06-14T10:46:52.3326036+02:00`, and I want convert this to a readable datetime, so I tried the following way:

```
$format = "d-m-Y H:i:s";
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimeStamp("2018-06-14T10:46:52.3326036+02:00");
$val = $date;
echo $val;
```

this will return: `1970-01-01 00:33:38.000000` that's of course wrong, which mistake I did?

Comment: @B001ᛦ - Thats a valid time stamp.

Comment: why there is 7 digits in microseconds 3326036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code:

```
$timestamp = "2018-06-14T10:46:52.3326036+02:00";
$date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($timestamp));
echo $date;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$format = "d-m-Y H:i:s"; 
echo date($format,strtotime("2018-06-14T10:46:52.3326036+02:00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:-

```
<?php

 echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime("2018-06-14T10:46:52.3326036+02:00")); 

?>
```